# can't get the box to rotate in media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm just trying this exercise on codeply. I'm attempting to get this box to rotate to 0 after the viewport is reduced to less than 1000px in width.  For some reason, all the other changes seem to work but not the rotation. Any ideas as to why?

Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
.red {
background-color:red;
width:100px;
height:100px;
transform: rotate(25deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size:60px;
}

.red {
  transform: rotate (0);
  background-color:green;
  position: relative;
  left:300px;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML part ?

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your css.

Your css:

```
.red {
  transform: rotate (0);
  background-color:green;
  position: relative;
  left:300px;
}
```

There is a space between `rotate` and `(0)`

Correct css:

```
.red {
  transform: rotate(0);
  background-color:green;
  position: relative;
  left:300px;
}
```